# Why is the movie title One Day?

Tags: title, one-day

This movie ends in non-linear fashion like Pulp Fiction and the plot is a tragic romantic story.

Why did they select the title "One Day" for this non-linear plot?

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every scene in the movie (and in the book on which it is based) is set on the same day of the year, 15th June (St Swithin's Day), running from when they meet in 1988 through to when she dies, in 2006, and on until the film's conclusion set in 2011.